# How to make a loop to count rows in datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, datagridview, datatable

I have a `datagridView` and `DataTable`. How to make a loop that add rows if it's not equal to 79 rows? If it's equal to 79 rows it will stop.

Comment: What all options have you tried?

Comment: I don't think you need a loop for this.  If you want to know the number of rows just check the value of `myDataTable.rows.Count`.

Comment: Or dgv.RowCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your code, this will make sure that you have padded to 79 rows in your data table.

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        int minRowCount = 79;
        while (dataTable.Rows.Count < minRowCount)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());
        }
```